# How do I make my model move with an armature's bones?

Tags: animation, armature

I'm making an animation and I need to use armatures, but I don't know how to make the model move with the bones. I know there is a certain command, but I can't recall it.

Comment: you should parent the model to the armature, set weights, and then pose the armature's bones.

Comment: Please mention the steps you did and provide screenshots of your problem and Upload your .blend file to be able to help you